# Put the ball in the middle of the panel with mouse enter event

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm six panel is a subset of a cube.
Now I want each of these panels inside the mouse when the white ball in the middle of the panel to be?
Figure 1.

![Image ][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxD1E.jpg

I've written this code, but the white ball in the middle of the cube is just not working.

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    if (gameObject.tag.ToString() == "Panel")
    {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");

        sphere.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
        sphere.transform.eulerAngles = gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with the picture provided, it is hard to know what you are trying to do. What are are you trying to do with the sphere? what is the cube used for? "I want each of these panels inside the mouse" What is that suppose to mean? What is the OnMouseEnter() for? For clicking on the cube or the sphere?

Comment: The question was corrected Please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Code inside "if" statement is not executed? Or it does something different from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Really hard to find out what do you want. Can you confim this? -> You want to put the white ball to the center of a panel when mouse is over.

Comment: yes,I want to put the white ball to the center of a panel when mouse is over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to place the ball on the face of the cube that the mouse cursor is hover over, this is an easy problem to solve if the center of the cube (origin) is at the geometric center, so if this is the case do the following:

1. Raycast against the cube (must have collider, probably box collider)
2. Using the hit.normal and the hit.point from the raycast result calculate the position of the white ball.
3. Set the position of the white ball

Example Code:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);    
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
{
    Vector3 ballPosition = hit.point + hit.normal * ballRadius;
    ballTransform.position = ballPosition;
}
```

ballRadius is the radius of the ball and can be obtained by accessing the ball's sphere collider.

ballTransform is the transform of the ball.